# Query to retrieve json objects from facebook graph api(search)

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api

I want a url like [this](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=google&v=2&alt=json&max-results=3) for the Facebook graph API search to retrieve data.

When I tried using this [url](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user), it gives

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

I will be using this over Android. Can someone please guide me in achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook's Graph API was public until recently when they added this `access_token`.

From their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) they explain how to create a temporary access token. Unfortunately, creating in this way, you will need to deal with some sort of job that will update (i.e. renew existing access token/generate a new access token) once in a while your access_token so you can be able to make use of the Graph API.

Most probably, there are some libraries out there that might deal with renewing or generating a new access token, but maybe it won't fit with your app.

So to avoid the previously mentioned "problem", I found there is a way to have a non-expiring access token.

What you will need to do is the following steps:

1. Create a Facebook account (if you don't have one or if you want to create an account just for development purposes)
2. Go at [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) page (Register as developer, activate account and whatnot)
3. Create a new app on the [Facebook Developers App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) page
4. Go to your app and at your `Settings`, click on `Edit Settings`.
5. Go at `Sandbox Mode` and select `Disabled`
6. On the left hand side, from the `Settings` section, click on Advanced.
7. At the `Authentication` section, check `App Type` and select `Web` (if it is not already that)
8. For the final step, go back to the `Basic` section in `Settings` and you will see two app specifics:

   `App ID` and `App Secret`

   You can make use of these two codes in order to benefit from a `access_token` which will not expire as follows: `APP ID|APP Secret` (observe the vertical bar between the codes)

So now you can make requests like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```

Observe that I did not mentioned in the url the `type=user`.
For your case, you will need to create expiring access tokens. You can quickly create a temporary token like this:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
 client_id={app-id}
  &client_secret={app-secret}
  &grant_type=client_credentials
```

(See [Access Tokens page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) from Facebook's documentation).
If you cannot find a solution that will deal automatically the refreshing of the access token, I can explain what I did by creating background job that will update it once in a while:

- You will need to save your current access token (maybe you can create manually one from the above mentioned way) in a file or maybe better in a database table.
- Once a month maybe, you will just need to make a request using this url:

  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

This will return a response similar to this:

```
access_token=NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN&expires=TIME_UNTIL_IT_EXPIRES.
```

As far as I remember, you will be able to use the newly create access token for 60 days with no problem (It was easier for me to generate a new one once a month making use of cron jobs).

So, having that response you can quickly do a simple regex:

```
access_token=(.*)&expires=(.*)
```

And you can do:

```
String newAccessToken = matcher.group(1);
```

Replace the existing access token in your file/db table and you're done.

With this access token you will be able to make your request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```